# Change text selection color (accent color) Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I've searched quite a lot now, but don't really know what to search for. I got a Xamarin project and I would like to change the highlight color and the little drag bars which you get when you select text. I'll include a picture so you can see what I'm talking about.

[image]

I want to get rid of that pink color and make it green.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that I know it had to do with 'colorAccent' I figured it out. If anyone else is having this problem, here you got a little guide:

Select `your_app.android` in the solution explorer.
Then go to Resources > Values > Style.xml.
In the style.xml you'll find this:

```
<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#70c1b3</item>
```

You can change the hex code in the color accent and it'll change the accent color throughout the whole app (alerts, selecting texts etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If your colorAccent is pink then get pink. If you change ColorAccent color to green then it's work perfectly.